# Preface text output with Print

Tags: printing

In the output of a script that calls Mathematica I would like to be able to differentiate lines printed by mathematica from lines printed by something else. I thought of prefacing lines printed by Mathematica with for example "m:". Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to change how `Print` behaves without having to change the code that uses `Print`?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I just want to change `Print` and not change any other part of the code.

Comment: Have you tried using the [Villegas-Gayley trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5149656/695132) to override `Print`?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Szabolcs, I used the [Villegas-Gayley method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5149656/695132)

```
Unprotect[Print];

Print[args___]:=Block[{$inMsg=True},
Print["|m:>",args,"<:m|"]
]/;!TrueQ[$inMsg]

Protect[Print];
```

This works well. Ideally I could do the same also for warning messages but I haven't quite figured out yet what the appropriate change would be to Message.

Comment: Just a small comment: you don't need ``result``, just write ``Print["|m:>", args, "<:m|"];``.

Comment: Of course you are right. Thanks.